# Search a list of string if it match a string with like operator

Tags: vb.net

I need to find in a list (of string) if any element is like a string.
I do it like this

```
For Each L As String In LikePaths
    If A Like L.ToLower Then Return True
Next
Return False
```

If i'd only like to know if the list contain an element, I can use list.contains(string). But it must be a way to check also if an element is like a string. I will have very big list of string and a for next is time consuming.

Comment: Where are `LikePaths` coming from?  My answer below addresses alternatives to the `For Each` loop you used, but none of them fundamentally change the process, so the performance won't be changed either.  You might find it works better to do the filtering when you get the path list originally i.e. file system operations that return a list of directories may accept a filter as an argument, and this may be more performant than doing a search using the `Like` operator later.

Comment: LikePaths is just a big list(of string) .

Comment: I know it is, but something has to have populated it.  That's what I'm asking about, what populated it originally?

Comment: The list is read from a database on startup. It's a pretty big list of about 20.000+ elements

Comment: Depending on whether the filter is fixed (same every time) or variable (might change from one invocation of the program to another, or even within the same invocation), you could consider filtering as you get the list from the database.  It would probably still be a bit slow, but it might be better to take the hit once on startup.

Comment: I'll experiment with this. Thank you very much for your help Craig. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Does A contain wild card characters?

Answer (score 1):

A `List(Of String)` is a container that implements `IEnumerable`, so any of the Linq functions can be used on it.  This includes `Any` and `Where`, both of which accept a lambda function for matching that can be written to use the `Like` operator.

For example,

```
If LikePaths.Any(Function(p) A Like p.ToLower()) Then
    '...
End If
```

Or,

```
For Each matchingPath In LikePaths.Where(Function(p) A Like p.ToLower())
    '...
Next
```

Note, however, that these will not give any better performance than the `For Each` loop you have written.  They're just more concise.

Comment: So is no point changing it? I thought I can yell better speeds with something like this...

Comment: @Andrei I would expect my example with `Any` to compile nearly identically to your function.  Your performance concern is the reason for the question I ask in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using wild card characters in your string to search for, I believe you have your operands backwards. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vb.Like);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.8);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue

The first operand is the string you want to check. The second is the pattern to match.

If you are not using any wildcards then `Like` just acts like `=` .

```
Private Function ContainsString(StringToSearchFor As String, lstToSearch As List(Of String)) As Boolean
    For Each L As String In lstToSearch
        If L Like StringToSearchFor Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

Here is the problem from the docs...

> The Like operator is currently not supported in .NET Core and .NET
> Standard projects.

It seems like this language specific operator is on its way out.